# Why is Winsock recvfrom() buffer returning 'E'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, networking, winsock

I'm trying to receive packets with Winsock and I am able to get a return from the recvfrom() command but when I try to print the data held in the buffer, I just get E.

This is where I use the recvfrom command:

```
    i = 0;
    while (i < 25) {
        data_len = recvfrom(raw_socket, rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&sender_addr, &sender_addr_size);

        std::cout << "Iteration: " << (i);
        printf("\nReceived packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(sender_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(sender_addr.sin_port));
        printf("Length of bytes received: %d\n", data_len);
        printf("Data: %s\n", rcvbuf);
        std::cout << "\n\n";
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

Example return when I run the code:
Iteration: 21
Received packet from *hidden IP*:0
Length of bytes received: 1385
Data: E

Its not an error with the size of the buffer and from a couple of hours searching online I cant find anything that describes my issue.
If anyone knows what's going on here I would very much appreciate an explanation or even better, a fix.

Other maybe useful code:

```
    char rcvbuf[10000];    
...
    // create a raw socket
    raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
    if (raw_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
...
    // Bind the IPv4 address to the socket
    if0.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(local_ip);
    if0.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if0.sin_port = htons(14996);;
    if (bind(raw_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&if0, sizeof(if0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind() failed with error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    else printf("bind() is OK!\n");
```

Thank you to every one that helped :)
The change I've made to print the binary data in the buffer (not accounting for endianness):

```
    // receive all packages in a while loop
    std::cout << "Connected on IPv4 Address: " << local_ip << "\n";
    i = 0;
    while (i < 2) {
        data_len = recvfrom(raw_socket, rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&sender_addr, &sender_addr_size);

        std::cout << (i);
        printf("\nReceived packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(sender_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(sender_addr.sin_port));
        printf("Length of bytes received: %d\n", data_len);
        printf("Data: ");
        //std::cout.write(rcvbuf, data_len);

        std::string s = rcvbuf;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < data_len;) {
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(s[i2]) << " ";
            i2 = i2 + 1;
        }

        std::cout << "\n--------------------------\n";
        memset(rcvbuf, 0, 10000);
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

Comment: It's probably binary data that just happens to have 0 as the second byte. Recall that `printf("Data: %s\n", rcvbuf);` assumes that `rcvbuf` points to a nul-terminated string, and so would stop printing at the first zero byte it encounters.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, I've changed the string type to other types and I'm getting different results. Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to convert `rcvbuf` to a `std::string` just to print it out. You can print the content of `rcvbuf` directly. Especially since your conversion suffers from the same bug as the original `printf` - assuming `rcvbuf` is a null terminated string when it really is not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper output functions to see the data.  You are using functions that assume that the string data is null-terminated:

`printf("Data: %s\n", rcvbuf);`

This will print what is in `rcvbuf` until the null-terminator is reached.  That point is more than likely less than `data_len` characters.

To properly print the data, you can use the `std::cout.write()` function:

`std::cout.write(rcvbuf, data_len);`

Comment: The same is true for `std::string s = rcvbuf;` too. It expects a null terminated string as input.  Use `std::string s(rcvbuf, data_len);` instead.